# Discontinuous bilinear form separately continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, bilinear-form

Do you have an example of a real normed space $V$ and a bilinear form $B : V \times V \to \mathbb R$ that is discontinuous but such that $B$ is separately continuous for each variable?

$V$ has to be not complete in order to not conflict Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $c_{00}\subset \ell^\infty$ be the space of sequences that are eventually zero. Define a bilinear form on it by 
$$B(x,y)=\sum_k x_k y_k$$
For each fixed $x$, the linear functional $y\mapsto B(x,y)$ is bounded: 
$$\left|\sum_k x_k y_k \right|\le \|y\|_\infty \sum_k |x_k|$$
(And same with $x,y$ interchanged.)

The form  $B$ is not jointly continuous: if $x_k=1/\sqrt{n}$ for $k\le n$ and $x_k =0$ otherwise, then the $\ell_\infty$ norm of $x$ can be arbitrarily small, yet $B(x,x)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be the subspace of $L^1(0,1)$ consisting of polynomials, and
$$B(f, g)=∫_0^1 f g$$
the bilinear form $B$ is continuous in each variables but it is not continuous.