# If a function is separately differentiable is it diferentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $X $, $Y $ and $Z $ normed vector spaces
$$f:X \times Y \to Z$$
Such that
$f(x, \cdot)$ is differentiable for all $x \in X $ and $f (\cdot ,y)$ is differentiable for all $y \in Y $. Is $f $ differentiable? If no, assumpting that $f $ is bilinear can we conclude that $f $ is differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not even true for $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$.  Your condition, in other words, is that the partial derivatives exist.  This is not sufficient for differentiability; a [standard counterexample](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Etom.vogel/gallery/node14.html) is
$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$
with $f(0,0)=0$.  Clearly $f(x,\cdot)$ is a differentiable function for every $x \ne 0$, and $f(0,\cdot)\equiv 0$ which is also differentiable.  Similarly, $f(\cdot, y)$ is differentiable for every $y$.  But $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$, as you may see by approaching the origin along the line $y=x$.

At [Discontinuous bilinear form separately continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478774/discontinuous-bilinear-form-separately-continuous?rq=1) you can find an example of a bilinear form on a normed space which is separately continuous, hence separately differentiable, but not continuous.